# Setting ID of object when importing seed data from JSON file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm importing objects in my seeds file from a json file like this:

```
[
{
    "email":"jon@a.com",
    "id":1,
    "league_id":1,
    "name":"Slim Jims are good for the heart...OH YEAH!",
    "owner":"Jon"
},
{
    "email":"robert@a.com",
    "id":2,
    "league_id":1,
    "name":"The Bucket List",
    "owner":"Robert"
}
]
```

my seeds file is:

```
require 'json'
Team.delete_all
JSON.parse(open("#{Rails.root}/doc/teams.json").read).each do |stuff|
   Team.create(stuff)
end
```

My problem is that it assigns some random id instead of the id from the json file.

Comment: The problem arises when these have already been set and deleted.

Comment: Ended up figuring out a way to work around it.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone wondering, you can do this by using this syntax instead of create:

```
JSON.parse(open("#{Rails.root}/doc/teams.json").read).each do |stuff|
    team = Team.new(stuff)
    team.id = stuff['id']
    team.save!
end
```